# Application and meaning of end iterator decrement

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
int get(int key) {
        if (m.count(key) == 0) return -1;
        freq[m[key].second].erase(iter[key]);      
        freq[m[key].second].push_back(key);        
        iter[key] = --freq[m[key].second].end();   
        if (freq[minFreq].size() == 0) ++minFreq;
        return m[key].first;
}

private:
    int cap, minFreq;
    unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>> m;
    unordered_map<int, list<int>> freq;
    unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator> iter;
```

I found this series of codes of solution on one of the Leetcode problems. It got me wondering what end iterator decrement actually means in this context and when would be the timing to use such format while you code. As a C++ beginner, I thought it would be great if it just stays

`iter[key] = freq[m[key].second].end();`

but the -- just really confuses me. In the context, we were supposed to find the LFU cache, and the line should be finding corresponding position of a value in the frequency list.

Comment: Doesn't the line just boil down to `iter[key] = --list.end()` so `iter[key]` is being set to an iterator with its next item being the last element in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list<int> li;
li.push_back(1);
li.push_back(2);
li.push_back(3);
```

`li.begin()` - pointer to ist element(as reference `li[0`]).

`li.end()` - pointer to null (element just after last element `li[2]`).

`--li.end()` - pointer to last element(`li[2]`). //your question

`li.rend()` - pointer to element just before the first element (before `li[0]`).

`li.rbegin()` - pointer to last element(`li[2]`).

`rbegin()` and `rend()` are reverse iterator you can learn more about them from geeksforgeeks.

Answer (score 0):

- `--` operation executes right before the actual statement.

---

#### Important

- Before you go any further into the `unordered_map` solution (which I also re-implemented that  btw):

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

static const struct LFUCache {

    inline LFUCache(const int capacity) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        size = 0;
    }

    inline const int get(const int key) {
        if (values.find(key) == values.end()) {
            return -1;
        }

        update(key);
        return values[key].first;
    }

    inline void put(const int key, const int value) {
        if (!capacity) {
            return;
        }

        if (values.find(key) != values.end()) {
            values[key].first = value;
            update(key);

        } else {
            if (size == capacity) {
                const ValueType evict = keys[least_freq_used].front();
                keys[least_freq_used].pop_front();
                values.erase(evict);
                iters.erase(evict);

            } else {
                size++;
            }

            values[key] = {value , 1};
            keys[1].emplace_back(key);
            iters[key] = --keys[1].end();
            least_freq_used = 1;
        }
    }

private:
    using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    ValueType capacity;
    ValueType size;
    ValueType least_freq_used = 0;
    std::unordered_map<ValueType, std::list<ValueType>> keys;
    std::unordered_map<ValueType, std::pair<ValueType, ValueType>> values;
    std::unordered_map<ValueType, std::list<ValueType>::iterator>iters;

    inline void update(const int key) {
        const ValueType freqency = values[key].second;
        const auto& iter = iters[key];
        values[key].second++;
        keys[freqency].erase(iter);
        keys[freqency + 1].emplace_back(key);
        iters[key] = --keys[freqency + 1].end();

        if (keys[least_freq_used].empty()) {
            least_freq_used++;
        }
    }
};
```

It's pretty important to note that doubly linked list is the right way to implement LFU cache. Here is one of the working Solutions from the Discussion Board based on DLL:

```
struct DListNode {
    int key;
    int value;
    int freq;
    DListNode* prev;
    DListNode* next;

    DListNode(int k, int v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
        freq = 1;
        prev = next = nullptr;
    }
};

struct DList {
    DListNode* sentinel;
    int size;

    DList() {
        size = 0;
        sentinel = new DListNode(-1, -1);
        sentinel->prev = sentinel->next = sentinel;
    }

    void prepend(DListNode* node) {
        node->next = sentinel->next;
        node->prev = sentinel;
        sentinel->next->prev = node;
        sentinel->next = node;
        ++size;
    }

    DListNode* pop(DListNode* node = nullptr) {
        if (size == 0) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        if (node == nullptr) {
            node = sentinel->prev;
        }

        node->prev->next = node->next;
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
        --size;
        return node;
    }
};

struct LFUCache {
    unordered_map<int, DListNode*> nodes;
    unordered_map<int, DList*> freqs;
    int capacity;
    int min_freq;

    LFUCache(int capacity) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        min_freq = 0;
    }

    void _update(DListNode* node) {
        if (freqs.find(node->freq) == freqs.end()) {
            freqs[node->freq] = new DList();
        }

        if (freqs.find(node->freq + 1) == freqs.end()) {
            freqs[node->freq + 1] = new DList();
        }

        freqs[node->freq]->pop(node);

        if (min_freq == node->freq && freqs[node->freq]->size == 0) {
            ++min_freq;
        }

        ++node->freq;
        freqs[node->freq]->prepend(node);
    }

    int get(int key) {
        if (nodes.find(key) == nodes.end()) {
            return -1;
        }

        DListNode* node = nodes[key];

        _update(node);

        return node->value;
    }

    void put(int key, int value) {
        if (capacity == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (nodes.find(key) != nodes.end()) {
            DListNode* node = nodes[key];
            _update(node);
            node->value = value;

        } else {
            if (nodes.size() == capacity) {
                if (freqs.find(min_freq) == freqs.end()) {
                    freqs[min_freq] = new DList();
                }

                DListNode* node = freqs[min_freq]->pop();

                if (node) {
                    nodes.erase(node->key);
                }
            }

            DListNode* node = new DListNode(key, value);
            nodes[key] = node;

            if (freqs.find(1) == freqs.end()) {
                freqs[1] = new DList();
            }

            freqs[1]->prepend(node);
            min_freq = 1;
        }
    }
};
```